# Is there a way to specify the current row in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

The code below creates a minimal data.table, shows the approach I am using with a for loop, and prints the desired output.

```
library(data.table)

# example data.table where "ID" corresponds to the row index
df <- data.table(ID = 1:5, parent_ID = c(0,1,1,3,3), value = paste0(rep("S", 5),1:5))

# unsort the rows and remove one so that ID no longer corresponds to the row index
df2 <- df[c(1, 4,5,3), .(ID, parent_ID, value)]

# this method below works
for(i in 2:nrow(df2))
{
  df2[i, "parent_value"] <- df2[which(df2[,ID] %in%  df2$parent_ID[i]), "value"]
}
df2
```

Output:

```
   ID parent_ID value parent_value
1:  1         0    S1         <NA>
2:  4         3    S4           S3
3:  5         3    S5           S3
4:  3         1    S3           S1
```

My question is if there is a different way to do this in data.table that avoids for loops. My guess is that it would look like the following, but it seems I need a way to reference the current row, thus the title question.

```
df2[, parent_value := df2[which(df2[,ID] %in% df2$parent_ID[i]), "value"]]
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: .I notation perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `match`:

```
df2[, parent_value := value[match(parent_ID, ID)]]
```

```
   ID parent_ID value parent_value
1:  1         0    S1         <NA>
2:  4         3    S4           S3
3:  5         3    S5           S3
4:  3         1    S3           S1
```

Comment: @3RK - since you edited the question and expected output, the solution becomes even simpler.  I changed answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f <- function(b) df[which(df2$ID %in% df2$parent_ID[b$id])]$value
df2[, parent_value:= f(.BY), by=.(id = 1:nrow(df2))]
```

Output:

```
   ID parent_ID value parent_value
1:  1         0    S1         <NA>
2:  4         3    S4           S4
3:  5         3    S5           S4
4:  3         1    S3           S1
```

You can use also use .I (as suggested in the comments by Severin), like this (`magrittr` pipe added for presentation clarity only:

```
df2[,id:=.I] %>% 
  .[, parent_value:=df[which(df2$ID %in% df2$parent_ID[id]), value], by=1:nrow(df2)] %>% 
  .[,id:=NULL] %>% 
  .[]
```

Comment: I edited a mistake in my question (changed df to df2 in my for loop method, changing the desired output). Making the change in the .BY method appears to work, but I haven't been able to get the .I method to work with this change.